# What is the reason for Powershell Excel SaveAs / Exception null-valued expression?

Tags: excel, oracle, powershell, batch-file, plsql

I'm working on a PowerShell script which unzips some `.csv` files, writes the contents inside an existing `.xlsx` file and saves this as a new `.xlsx`.

After some calculation I start a batch file from my PL/SQL code with `DBMS.SCHEDULE`. After the `.bat` file did some preparation it starts the PowerShell script.

I'm getting no error if I run the `.bat` file manually in a Windows command prompt window.
But I get an error while saving the `.xlsx` file if it is started from PL/SQL.

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

I tried to search in world wide web for a solution on this error but couldn't find one.

This is the line which produces the error message:

```bsh
$WB.SaveAs($fileName, 51, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $false, $false, 1, 2) | Out-Null
```

Here is the whole code:

```cs
#Unzip Files
function Unzip($file, $destination){
    Expand-Archive $file -Destination $destination -Force

    if (Test-Path $file) {
        Remove-Item $file
    }
}

#Add file to existing zip
function addZip($file, $destination){
    Compress-Archive -Path $file -Update -DestinationPath $destination
}

#Write CSV into XLSX
function WriteFile($row, $column, $range){
    foreach ($content in Get-Content $f.FullName) { #Get row
        #If value not empty
        if ($content) {
            #Set value to cell
            $WS.Cells.Item($row, $column) = $content

            $colA = $ws.Range("$range$row")
            $colrange = $ws.Range("$range$row")

            #Split value by delimiter
            #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns
            $colA.TextToColumns($colrange, 1, -4142, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $true, "|") | Out-Null

            $row = $row + 1
        }
    }
}

#Start
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#Disable alerts
$XL.EnableEvents = $false
$XL.DisplayAlerts = $false
$XL.ScreenUpdating = $false

$param = $args[0].SubString(0, $args[0].IndexOf(".")) #Get name
$currentPath = Get-Location
$newPath = "$currentPath\$param\" #Temp new folder

#Create temp folder if exists
if (!(Test-Path $newPath)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $newPath
}

#Unzip
Unzip "$currentPath\$param.zip" $newPath

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $newPath -Recurse #Get files
$XL.Workbooks.Open("$currentPath\test.xlsx")
$WB = $xl.ActiveWorkbook
$fileName = "$newPath"+"test_$param.xlsx"

#Loop through files
foreach ($f in $files) {
    if ($f.Basename.ToUpper() -like "*A") {
        $WS = $WB.Sheets.Item("A")
        $WS.Activate() | Out-Null
        WriteFile 10 1 "A" #Row / Column
        addZip $f.FullName "$currentPath\$param.zip"
    } elseif ($f.Basename.ToUpper() -like "*B") {
        $WS = $WB.Sheets.Item("B")
        $WS.Activate() | Out-Null
        WriteFile 11 1 "A" #Row / Column
        addZip $f.FullName "$currentPath\$param.zip"
    } elseif ($f.Basename.ToUpper() -like "*C") {
        $WS = $WB.Sheets.Item("C")
        $WS.Activate() | Out-Null
        WriteFile 12 1 "A" #Row / Column
        addZip $f.FullName "$currentPath\$param.zip"
    }
}

try {
    #Delete File if exists
    if ((Test-Path $fileName)) {
        Remove-Item -Path $fileName -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
    }

    #Save
    $WB.SaveAs($fileName, 51, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $false, $false, 1, 2) | Out-Null
} catch {
    New-Item "$currentPath\log.txt" -ItemType file
    $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message, $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber |
        Out-File "$currentPath\log.txt"
} finally {
    #Close, Quit
    $WB.Close($false) | Out-Null
    $XL.Workbooks.Close()
    $XL.Quit() | Out-Null
}

try {
    addZip $fileName "$currentPath\$param.zip"
} catch {
    New-Item "$currentPath\log1.txt" -ItemType file
    $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message, $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber |
        Out-File "$currentPath\log1.txt"
}

#Delete folder
if ((Test-Path $newPath)) {
    Remove-Item -Path $newPath -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
}

#Release ComObject
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($XL)
spps -n Excel
```

This is the .bat file which runs the Powershell script:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File C:\Scripts\write_to_excel.ps1 %1
```

This is the PL/SQL code which runs the .bat file:

```sql
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL',
                               job_action            => 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe',
                               number_of_arguments   => 4,
                               job_type              => 'executable',
                               enabled               => FALSE);

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL', 1, '/q');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL', 2, '/c');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL', 3, 'c:\Scripts\run_powershell.bat');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL', 4, 'test_files.zip');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job (job_name              => 'SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL', use_current_session   => TRUE);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        log_trace_message ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL: ' || SQLERRM);
        log_trace_message ('SCHEDULE_POWERSHELL: ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);
END;
```

Comment: Have you checked in the .bat file script that `%1` has the value you expect?

Comment: @lit yes the value is correct. It does every step of my script except the save method.

Comment: When PL/SQL starts cmd.exe, under what user account is it operating?

Comment: FYI! The problem was, that PL/SQL started the script with a user without permission. I coulnd't figure out, how to change the user for the execution. I could solve mit problem by calling schtasks /create and declare the user/password. Thank for help.